# Uniform convergence of the serie $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n + |z|}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

Show that the following serie is uniformly convergent in $\mathbb{C}$
$$\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n + |z|}$$
This serie is absolutely convergent in $\mathbb{C}$?

I showed that the series is not absolutely convergent, just consider $z = 0$ and we have the harmonic serie. In addition, using the Leibniz test to alternating series I also showed that the series is pointwise convergent, but I can't show that the serie is uniformly convergent, someone can help me? Thank you

Comment: $\frac{1}{n+x}-\frac{1}{n+1+x}= \frac{1}{(n+x)(n+1+x)}$

Comment: @reuns Sorry, but i dont understand how this can help me

Comment: $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{2n-1+x}-\frac1{2n+x}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The series converges uniformly for all $z \in \mathbb{C}$ by the [Dirichlet test](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_Test_for_Uniform_Convergence) which states that $\sum a_n(z)b_n(z)$ converges uniformly if the partial sums $\sum_{k=1}^n a_k(z)$ are uniformly bounded in modulus and $b_n(z) \downarrow 0$ as $n \to \infty$ monotonically and uniformly.

Here we have for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $z \in \mathbb{z}$,

$$a_k(z) = (-1)^{k-1} \implies \left|\sum_{k=1}^n a_k(z) \right| \leqslant 1$$

We also have

$$b_n(z) = \frac{1}{n + |z|} \leqslant \frac{1}{n} \to 0,$$

where it is clear that the convergence to $0$ is uniform and monotone since $b_{n+1}(z) \leqslant b_n(z)$.